# about the equivalent R code for forvalues in Stata

Tags: r, stata

When we deal with the longitudinal recurrent events. I would like to detect the events which meet some condition.

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3), rep(4,4)), 
               event=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,1,1,1,1),
               eventcount=c(1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3,1,2,3,4), 
               firstevent=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1,0,0,0), 
               time=c(100, 250, 150, 300, 240, 400, 150, 200, 320, 360,100,210,220,235) )
```

When we want to detect events which occurred from 100 days to 150 days after the first event.
In Stata, we can use

```
gen event2=1 if id==id[_n-1]& time-time[_n-1]>100 & time-time[_n-1]<=150 & firstevent[_n-1]==1 & firstevent==0 & event==1
forvalues i = 2/4 {
replace event2=1 if id==id[_n-`i']& time-time[_n-`i']>100 &time-time[_n-`i']<=150 & firstevent[_n-`i']==1 & firstevent==0 & event==1
}
```

I would like to obtain the dataset below.

```
data_after <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3), rep(4,4)), 
               event=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,1,1,1,1),
               eventcount=c(1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3,1,2,3,4), 
               firstevent=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1,0,0,0), 
               time=c(100, 250, 150, 300, 240, 400, 150, 200, 320, 360,100,210,220,235),
               afterevent=c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1))
```

How can we write equivalent R code for this Stata code?
In the original data, we have more ids and more recurrent events.

Answer (score 0):

This would correspond to your output:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(afterevent = ifelse(time <= (time[firstevent == 1] + 150) & 
                          (time >= time[firstevent == 1] + 100), 1, NA))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 6
# Groups:   id [4]
      id event eventcount firstevent  time afterevent
   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1     1          1          1   100         NA
 2     1     1          2          0   250          1
 3     1     0          0          0   150         NA
 4     1     0          0          0   300         NA
 5     2     1          1          1   240         NA
 6     2     1          2          0   400         NA
 7     2     0          0          0   150         NA
 8     3     1          1          1   200         NA
 9     3     1          2          0   320          1
10     3     0          3          0   360         NA
11     4     1          1          1   100         NA
12     4     1          2          0   210          1
13     4     1          3          0   220          1
14     4     1          4          0   235          1
```